# Как управлять отображением камер на мониторах

Tags: unity3d

Проблема заключается в том, что я не нашел в документации как управлять отображением камер на экранах. У меня есть 4 экрана и как мне запустить отображение камеры[2] на экран[4]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Компонент **Camera** > в нем есть опция **Target Display**, где в выпадающем списке можно выбрать нужный дисплей, что бы назначить его на данную камеру

нумерация дисплеев аналогична настройкам операционной системы

[image: компонент камера]

для примера я выбрал вывод изображения данной камеры на 2 монитор

**так же, нужно будет через код активировать дополнительные дисплеи:**

```
    //активация дополнительных дисплеев
    //если дисплеев больше одного то..
    if (Display.displays.Length > 1)
    {
        // активируем нужное кол-во дисплеев
        Display.displays[1].Activate();
        Display.displays[2].Activate();
    }
```

добавлю еще, что в окне **Game** можно переключатся между дисплеями:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Благодарю, это именно то, что мне не нужно. Я уже объяснил ситуацию. У меня 4 экрана, как мне регулировать отображение камеры[2] на мониторе[4].

Comment: выбрать камеру 2 и выставить в ее компоненте Camera -> опцию Target Display на Display 4

Comment: ладно, я уже выяснил что юнити номера дисплеев берет из винды

Comment: ну да, я так и написал в ответе изначально: "нумерация дисплеев аналогична настройкам операционной системы"

Comment: я прочитал до редакции твоего ответа

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и выставляем "Компонент Camera > в нем есть опция Target Display, где в выпадающем списке можно выбрать нужный дисплей, что бы назначить его на данную камеру" как описал сверху человек. нумерацию дисплеев юнити берет из винды. спасибо

Comment: чем это отличается от уже данного ответа? И то, что вы начали со скриншота виндовых настроек сильно сбивает с толку - я чуть было не решил, что это вообще не ответ про юнити.